# How update operation works in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

As per hibernate documentation , below is the definition of update operation

`void update(Object object)` throws `HibernateException`
Update the persistent instance with the identifier of the given detached instance. If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier, an exception is thrown. This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with `cascade="save-update"`.

I have a question on statement **If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier, an exception is thrown.** . I think when it is saying If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier it means if the session (in which we doing update operation) already  contains persistent instance with the same identifier, exception will be thrown. But if the second level cache contains the persistent instance with the same identifier, update operation will update the object., it wont throw any exception **Right?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the statement tells about the Session, not the second level cache. Second level cache work at session factory level and it exists as long as the session factory is alive. And if object with same identifier attached with the **session**(not second level cache), then only the exception will be thrown. If not, then it will update the object in database as well as second level cache.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. The update should not throw an exception if an instance with the same identifier is in the second level cache.

The sentence you highlighted isn't very clear but I think you're correct in your assumption. Perhaps you could comment on the http://jboss.org forums and see if they can clarify the wording, maybe even improve it.